# Git Hook Post Update File Not Running

Tags: git, bash, hook

I have a test project set up locally at;

```
~/development/test/
```

I have git initialised on it and I can push to my remote "test" repo fine. No issues with that.

I can run my post-update hook **manually** from the command line;

```
./post-update
```

It will launch a web browser because the file has the following contents;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hook is running........."
python -mwebbrowser http://example.com
```

But when I do a `git push -u origin master` the file just does not seem to run. None of what is in the bash script seems to happen.

I have the file permissions set up correctly as stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523624/2277139)

Any ideas on what else to try?

Comment: Do you have error message after doing the `git push` ?

Comment: @Flows No errors at all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the wrong hook. [Git hook documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) says :

> **post-update** is invoked by `git-receive-pack` on the **remote repository**,
>   which happens when a git push is done on a local repository. **It
>   executes on the remote repository** once after all the refs have been
>   updated.

You would like a *post-push* hook which doesn't exist. Instead you could used **pre-push** hook.

> **pre-push** is called by `git push`. If this hook exits with a non-zero
>   status, git push will abort without pushing anything.

The web browser will be opened before the push to be performed but if you open it on a background task (with character `&`) and return `0` it should do what you are looking for.

Your script will became

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hook is running........."
python -mwebbrowser http://example.com &
exit 0
```

Comment: ah, that does the trick. although, I will need to read/understand the docs as I will want to share this hook with people but as of right now it's only on my local machine, right?

Comment: Yes, it is difficult to share a hook. You can create a symbolic link to your hook in all developers `.git/hook` folder, or commit a folder `hook` with hooks and script to launch to install them. But AFAIK there is not a simple way to deploy a hook with git.