# How to automatically stage commits from a submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

I am working on a project containing a submodule and a submodule at the same time.
As they are continually build locally, I need to update the submodule at least on every commit I make inside of it.

Here is a `post-commit` hook inspired by [this post on hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895559/git-hook-to-update-superproject-on-submodule-change) and [this post on submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359204/git-command-line-know-if-in-submodule) and also by [this for cleaning the env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058363/git-failing-to-find-the-index-when-in-submodule-index-file-open-failed-not-a) and [for the debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084100/post-commit-hook-not-running)

this is already a working solution, but if there is a better way I will accept an answer.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

### functions

exec_push()
{
ping -c 1 heise.de 2>&1 >> /dev/null # check connectivity
PING_RESULT=$?
if [ $PING_RESULT -eq "0" ]
then
    git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand --quiet
else
    echo "sorry no internet connectivity"
    exit 1
fi
}

### end functions

echo "post-commit started"
branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
echo "running on branch $branch"
superproject="$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)"
echo "running for superproject $superproject"
current_submodule="$(pwd)"
echo "adding submodule $current_submodule"

if [ "$branch" = "master" ]
then
    exec_push
    env -i git -C "$superproject" add .
fi

echo "post-commit finished"
```

instead of commiting the change, it only stages them, so they are commited with the next full commit.

Answer (score 0):

A basic `post-commit`-hook:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "post-commit started"
branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
echo "running on branch $branch"
superproject="$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)"
echo "running for superproject $superproject"
current_submodule="$(pwd)"
echo "adding submodule $current_submodule"

if [ "$branch" = "master" ]
then
    env -i git -C "$superproject" add .
fi

echo "post-commit finished"
```

Comment: My complains about the code are: `env -i` clears too much, it could, for example, clear `$PATH` if my `git` is in a non-standard path; use [`unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394777/7976758). `git add .` adds too much; the command could add changes in the superproject not related to the submodule; there have to be a way to name the submodule in `git add <submodule>`.

Comment: I will add the `unset rev-parse` directly and I will have a look for adding, but as the cwd isn't changed it should add the submodule